# With holographic remoting player app, I always see just a black screen with 'receiving...' text

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm a new user for hololens2. Recently, I am using hologrphic remoting player app because it can support my application tests.

What I expected to show on hololens when I set up this app with unity to use is my scene. However, it show me just black screen with 'receiving...' text.

I even wait for about 5 minutes after this text showed up, but this situation never changed. Plus, in unity, the game tab should show my scene, but it shows black screen too whenever I click the 'start' button to use the app.

How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information about what steps you have tried and what tutorial you are using? And the information about the version of Unity and which XR pipeline (legacy XR pipeline or XR SDK or OpenXR)  you are using is necessary. Without any specific context the above information does not make any sense to us.

Comment: Hi, Hernando! First, I followed this tutorial which is from Microsoft docs. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-play-mode?tabs=openxr) And I also followed this youtube video for scene setting (https://youtu.be/MWjVQN4y_oM) I installed holographic remoting player app(ver: 2.6.2.0) in my hololens2, and my unity version is 2020.3.11f1 personal. I'm not sure which pipeline I'm using, but I think it is OpenXR one. (I added project setting screens on this post. You can check it by clicking 'enter image description here' texts.)

Comment: More specifically, my steps are exactly same with the video I mentioned. The steps are came from microsoft docs.

Comment: Can the scene correctly work without holographic remoting? Or it always shows a black screen whether you add holographic remoting or not? If so, please check the setting of your camera first, it is recommended to follow this [step-by-step tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-01) to add and automatically configure Mixed Reality Toolkit in your Unity project.